# Don't write comma after last element in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function that gets data from a database and displays it in the view:

```js
function GetUsers() {
  let url = "/Home/GetUsers";
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.dir(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        $('#taskresult3').append('<b>' + data[i].UserName + "-" + data[i].RoleName + "," + '</b>');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

It displays it with comma, but after the last `Username+RoleName` it adds a 
comma too. As I understood I need to get last iteration of for loop? How I can fix this problem?

Comment: _“As I understood I need to get last iteration of for loop?”_ - easier to do it the other way around - check whether you are in the _first_ loop iteration, and if not, output the comma _before_ the current item ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I usually make a little trick for this cases:

```
var separator = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  $('#taskresult3').append(separator + '<b>' + data[i].UserName + "-" + data[i].RoleName + '</b>');
  separator = ",";
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 7):

Simply check if the current element is the last element and if so, don't add the comma:

```
$('#taskresult3').append('<b>'+ data[i].UserName +"-"+ data[i].RoleName + (i === data.length - 1 ? "" : ",")+'</b>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont add comma for the last element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  if (i === data.length - 1)
    $('#taskresult3').append('<b>' + data[i].UserName + "-" + data[i].RoleName '</b>');
  else
    $('#taskresult3').append('<b>' + data[i].UserName + "-" + data[i].RoleName + "," + '</b>');
}
```

There is one more approach using `.join()` on arrays

```
var _html = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    var _inhtml = '<b>' + data[i].UserName + "-" + data[i].RoleName+'</b>';
    _html.push(_inhtml);

}
$('#taskresult3').append(_inhtml.join(","));
```

With this you can cut down the overhead of manipulating DOM multiple times.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's most likely because the code itself isn't very DRY and is rather unsightly because of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the comma and improve your logic by building the HTML in an array, then using `join()` to display it, like this:

```js
success: function(data) {
  var html = data.map(function(item) {
    return data[i].UserName + ' - ' + data[i].RoleName;
  });
  $('#taskresult3').append(html.join(',');
}
```

Also, keep in mind the semantic use of the `<b>` tag:

> However, you should not use `<b>` for styling text; instead, you should use the CSS `font-weight` property to create boldface text.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

I'd suggest placing the HTML you append within a container that has `font-weight: bold` applied to it through CSS.

Comment: The comma must be bold as well.

Comment: In which case you can apply a CSS rule to a containing element.

Comment: Ok, but is missing in your solution.

Comment: True. I updated it to advise to use CSS instead of the `<b>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` and `join` to solve this, instead of using a loop.

```
$('#taskresult3').append('<b>' + data.map(item => item.UserName + "-" + item.RoleName).join(',</b><b>') + '</b>')
```

`map` would convert the array, to an array of `item.UserName + "-" + item.RoleName`, this array then would be joined together using `,</b><b>` and the last part that is then missing is the first `<b>` and the last `</b>`